# Transfer of antibodies from mother to fetus

Tags: human-biology, immunology, antibody

My questions: When does fetus begins to acquire antibodies from mother? Does it continue throughout the pregnancy?

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_immunity

> This occurs around the third month of gestation.

From Helena Curtis Biology :

> During the last month of pregnancy , the baby usually begins to acquire antibodies from its mother,....

I believe that both these sources are reliable but they contradict when the transfer of antibodies starts.

Comment: only `IgG-1, 3 & 4` cross the placenta. The transfer of antibodies would start as soon as umbilical vein develops.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Yup, those are the antibodies that are transfered but I am interested in when they are transfered.

Comment: as i recall, they are actually gathered by cells and actively transported across the placental barrier.  there is an Fc receptor.  a trained immunologist might be the best person to answer this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are technically correct.  Here's a review that goes into some detail about the process: [IgG Placental Transfer in Healthy and Pathological Pregnancies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3251916).  It's worth a read if you're interested in the subject.  In particular, it cites a [study of immunoglobulin transport](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8955500) which:

> demonstrated a continuous rise in IgG levels in the fetal circulation between 17 and 41 weeks of gestation. Fetal IgG concentrations were only 5%–10% of the maternal levels at weeks 17–22 but reached 50% of the maternal concentrations at weeks 28–32. The majority of IgG is acquired by the fetus during the last 4 weeks of pregnancy, and fetal IgG concentrations usually exceed maternal ones by 20%–30% at full term.

So it begins a wee bit before week 17, so definitely within the **second** trimester, but it is only by the **third** that concentrations begin to be truly meaningful.  However, most of the antibody acquired, going above the maternal level, is done in the last **month**.